# Redirect to https:// with www apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, 301-redirect

I am redirecting all http:// request to https:// using apache2 host .conf file like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    Redirect / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    #more details here
</VirtualHost>
```

This is working fine and redirecting all request to https://

Now I want to redirect my non-www request to www(so https://example.com to https://www.example.com). I tried to add these below lines before and then after the above 443 block. But no luck :(

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Any idea how I can enable this without .htaccess.

Please help..

Comment: Do `example.com` and `www.example.com` have distinct IP's?  Are you running all of this on the same apache server?  You could use dedicated IPs to make clear which VHost is which or use SNI as explained at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106471/is-it-necessary-to-have-dedicated-ip-address-to-install-ssl-certificate/6106500#6106500  Otherwise apache will pick one of the vhosts and ignore the other.

Comment: Wouldn't enabling HSTS result in the same?

Comment: I've used configuration similar to the OP which worked great (except I used the IP address instead of * -- that could be the difference, which would be too bad, but maybe the OP should try). Eyeballing it, not able to see what's wrong with this. Anything in the logs please?

Comment: The configuration you posted works, maybe you got a web browser cache trouble

Answer (score 0):

You want to add the redirect to the existing `*:443` vhost.  Something like this should do it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Put that before any other `RewriteRule` sections.

Comment: Using rewriting is overkill/unecessary. Redirects are faster.

Comment: Go ahead and add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is already correct.

And you need to define `*:443` with `NameVirtualHost`.

Use this configuration where `# more details here` is all of your SSL setup, as you already have:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    # more details here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect / https://www.example.com/
    # more details here
</VirtualHost>
```

You'll need your SSL certificate details in *each* `VirtualHost` container, even if they are the same.

Please *don't* use additional IPv4 addresses - this use case does not require consuming additional IP addresses. HTTP/1.1 can handle multiple domains on one IP address, including with SSL.